# Why "reduce to", not the other way around?

Tags: terminology, reductions

This action confuses me for a while. As you know, once we come up with a problem and we want to know how hard it is, we will do the "reduction". Intuitively, if we prove *problem B* is as hard as *problem A*, we can know the complexity boundary of *B*. But if *problem B* is harder than *A*, why we call the reduction process -- reduce *problem A* to *problem B*, not reduce *problem B* to *A*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different types of reduction, but generally, if we say we reduce problem A to problem B, it means something like:  if we had a way to solve B, we could use that to solve A.  Some reductions may allow to use B as a black box.  Others might require that "yes" instances of A map to "yes" instances of B, and that "no" instances map as well.  Or, it may be something simpler, like "hey, I already have a great solution to problem B, and now with just a simple transform, I can use it to solve problem A."
In all forms, it implies something related to "we could solve A if we had solutions to B".

What that means has something to do with what is known.  If B is an easy problem to solve, then A reducing to B tells us that solving A is no harder than solving B, plus doing the reduction from A to B.  In that case, an easy reduction, to an easy problem, proves that A is easy.

On the other hand, especially in the context of hardness results, we would usually reduce a known difficult problem (A here) to B, and that would show that, because A is hard, but transforming an instance of A into B is easy, B must also be hard, because if B were easy, it would give a solution to the known A problem.

So basically, for an easy reduction from A to B, it proves 2 things:  A is not harder than B, and B is not easier than A.  Yes, those are the same thing, but usually, you only care about one of them, depending on whether you know A to be difficult, or B to be easy.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is pretty sufficient! So could I say that -- "reduce" describe the process of "transforming'' the problem A to problem B which might have a good solution already. "Reduce'' does not mean simplify the "problem"?

Comment: That would be the proper usage if you are reducing to a problem B with a known solution.